# Eclipse, LiClipse with PyDev debugger and Python 2.7 fails in debug mode but in run mode goes well

Tags: python-2.7, pydev

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

print('Prueba 2.7')
```

[image]

**Eclipse / LiClipse error:**

Unexpected error setting up the debugger

Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking
[image]

**Console error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ORJ1GA\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle import pydev_imports, pydev_log
  File "C:\Users\ORJ1GA\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.5.0.201809011628\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_imports.py", line 59, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import quote, quote_plus, unquote_plus #@UnresolvedImport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 246, in <module>
    """
AttributeError: attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

[image]

Comment: To get best responses, please consider pasting your code (smallest case possible) in the question. This is because everybody here wants to help but is not a good practice providing outside links in order to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Was explicitly the urlib library, I deleted this folder and works all the projects that does not use this library.